# Missing import scala.collection.parallel in Scala 2.13

Tags: scala, parallel-collections, scala-2.13

[Parallel collections](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html) in Scala 2.12 were importable out-of-the-box like so

```
import scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParVector
val pv = new ParVector[Int]
```

however why in Scala 2.13 package `scala.collection.parallel` seems to be missing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Parallel collections have been moved in Scala 2.13 to separate module [scala/scala-parallel-collection](https://github.com/scala/scala-parallel-collections)

> This Scala standard module contains the package
> scala.collection.parallel, with all of the parallel collections that
> used to be part of the Scala standard library.
>
> For Scala 2.13, this module is a separate JAR that can be omitted from
> projects that do not use parallel collections.

thus from 2.13 onwards we need the following dependency

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parallel-collections" % "1.0.0"
```

and to enable `.par` extension method import

```
import scala.collection.parallel.CollectionConverters._
```

Corresponding scaladoc is also no longer available from [2.13 API docs](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/) but instead is published at [javadoc.io/doc/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parallel-collections_2.13](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parallel-collections_2.13/latest/index.html).