# Missing par method from Scala collections

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, scala-collections, scala-2.13

I tried to convert a sequential list to a parallel one in Intellij, but I get the error

> Cannot resolve symbol par

on the `.par` method call:

```
import scala.collection.parallel.immutable._
...
val parList = List(1,2,3).par
```

According to https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html, one must simply

> invoke the par method on the sequential collection, list. After that, one can use a parallel collection in the same way one would normally use a sequential collection.

What makes me wonder is that I did not find any `par` method in the current immutable list api of scala: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

But there's even a dedicated scala doc-page for sequential to parallel conversion which uses the `par` method: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/conversions.html

**About my setup**

I'm on Arch Linux with OpenJDK 10 set at language level 9 (in Intellij) and scala-sdk-2.13.0.

Imported library dependencies:

- `scala-library` (2.13.0)
- `scala-parallel-collections` (2.13.0)

Comment: Did you `import scala.collection.parallel.CollectionConverters._` ?

Comment: I didn't. And to do so solves my problem! Thanks :)
As you do not get import recommendations for Scala (as opposed to Java programming) in Intellij, do you have any ideas how I could have discovered that solution? I'm still new to Scala.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing import scala.collection.parallel in Scala 2.13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542568/missing-import-scala-collection-parallel-in-scala-2-13)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @Thilo mentioned in a comment, I was missing the following import which is necessary since Scala 2.13:

`import scala.collection.parallel.CollectionConverters._`

> Source: https://github.com/scala/scala-parallel-collections/issues/22

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the import:

```
import scala.collection.parallel.CollectionConverters._
```

you also need to add dependency in pom.xml of your maven project:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-parallel-collections_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```