# Trying to use .par in Scala 2.13 gives me “Error: value par is not a member of”

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, scala-collections, scala-2.13

I'm learning [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/). While taking Martin Odersky's MOOC, I watched his [talk 
 at OSCON Java 2011 titled "Working Hard to Keep It Simple"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jg1AheF4n0). In his presentation, he uses the `.par` method to make a collection parallel. But when I try to use `.par` in Scala, for example:

```
val numbers = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
val (evens, odds) = numbers.par partition(_ % 2 == 0)
```

I get this error:

```
Error:(6, 40) value par is not a member of List[Int]
did you mean map, max, or span?
```

What happened to the `.par` method in Scala 2.13?

Comment: The parallel collections were removed from the std lib in  `2.13` and moved to an external library. You can search for that.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/57287607/14955